# spring boot jpa - generate and save test data

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to fill my DB with alot of test data, so i wrote a CommandLineRunner to save around 2k entities.

It Work's - but it takes FOREVER to finish (5-10min) - Am i handling this the wrong way ?

```
@Component
public class DbSeederTest implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    FirstRepo firstRepo;
    @Autowired
    SecondRepo secondRepo;
    @Autowired
    ThirdRepo thirdRepo;

    private List<FirstEnt> firstList = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<SecondEnt> secondList = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<ThirdEnt> thirdList = new ArrayList<>();


    private void generateTestData() {
          // generate alot of entities, and add them to the Lists
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {

        System.out.println("saving ents...");

        generateTestData();

        try {

            firstRepo.save(firstList);
            secondRepo.save(secondList);
            thirdRepo.save(thirdList);

        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I dont know why its taking too much of time, but you can decrease the time surely by using thread concept. Because data is already populated after `generateTestData();`, so now call every repo save method in different thread.

Answer (score 0):

You can try and take advantage of the bulk insert feature.

There is hibernate property which you can define as one of the properties of hibernate's `SessionFactory`:

```
<property name="jdbc.batch_size">250</property>
```

With this batch setting you should have output like:

`insert into Table(id , name) values (1, 'na1') , (2, 'na2') ,(3, 'na3').`.

instead of

```
insert into Table(id , name) values (1, 'na1');
insert into Table(id , name) values (2, 'na2');
insert into Table(id , name) values (3, 'na3');
```

In your repository save methods you would be persisting around 250 (you have to do some testing what is the sweet spot performance-wise in your application) entities.. and then flushing your session for best performance until all of the data has been saved:

```
public void save(List<Item> itemList){
  for ( int i=0; i<itemList.size(); i++ ) {   
      session.save(itemList.get(i));

      if ( i % 250 == 0 ) { //250, same as the JDBC batch size
          //flush a batch of inserts and release memory:
          session.flush();
          session.clear();
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can decrease the time taken by using Threading concept.

Before calling `save` method of all repo you have the data after calling `generateTestData();`.

So change your code little bit

```
Thread thread1 = new Thread(()->firstRepo.save(firstList));
Thread thread2 = new Thread(()->secondRepo.save(secondList));
Thread thread3 = new Thread(()->thirdRepo.save(thirdList));
thread1.start();
thread2.start();
thread3.start();
```

The `Thread` run method is override using Java 8 feature you can do this in Java 7 as follows:

```
Thread thread1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        firstRepo.save(firstList);

    }
});
```

Hope this helps.